# How can I reference a test Remote Access application while testing my managed package?

Tags: apex, visualforce

In my managed package I have included a Remote Access application that references my external web site to handle various integration tasks including:

- Product fulfillment requests/cancellations
- Client specific options to populate Visualforce dropdown elements

In my supporting Apex Controller Extension classes, I reference the live site URL, but for testing purposes I would like to reference a test server so orders are not fulfilled.

Is there a suggested approach for having production and test Remote Access applications accessible within a managed package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this managed with [Custom Settings](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/cs_about.htm). You could either have a URL field or just a checkbox. Everywhere you reference the URL, you'd check the custom setting instead. You'd also need to provide a Visualforce page to manage your application settings.

The benefit of using Custom Settings is that they can be accessed without SOQL and are fast to access.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This approach has worked so far. I ended up with a default value in the code and was able to override the value for testing with a custom setting.